# Find all unique values in column separated by comma

Tags: r, strsplit

I have multiple observations of one species with different observers / groups of observers and want to create a list of all unique observers. My data look like this:

```
data <- read.table(text="species observer
1 A,B
1 A,B
1 B,E
1 B,E
1 D,E,A,C,C
1 F"               , header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My output should return a list of all unique observers - so:

```
A,B,C,E,F
```

I tried to substring the data in column C using the following command  but that only returns the unique combinations of observers.

```
all_observers <- unique(strsplit(as.character(data$observer), ","))

all_observers
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "B" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "D" "E" "A" "C" "C"

[[4]]
[1] "F"
```

Comment: You need to `unlist` before your do `unique`. Try `unique(unlist(strsplit(...)))`

Comment: @Gregor   Add as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to `unlist` before you do the `unique`:

```
all_observers <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(data$observer), ",")))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `separate_rows` on the 'observer', get the `distinct` rows, grouped by 'species', and `paste` the 'observer'

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   separate_rows(observer) %>% 
   distinct %>% 
   group_by(species) %>% 
   summarise(observer = toString(observer))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `scan()`

```
unique(scan(text=data$observer, what="", sep=","))
# Read 14 items
# [1] "A" "B" "E" "D" "C" "F"
```